# So too did ...?

Tags: inversion

As an example, look at this sentence:

> So **too did** some of the social means and cultural criteria of the north expand southward.

I paraphrase this into:

> So some of the social means and cultural criteria of the north expand**ed** southward **too**.

- (If I am right)

Now, What was the original sentence of the below?

> So **too did** a lot of the north's fighters.

Comment: If the original sentence is "So a lot of the north's fighters did too", why the paraphrase isn't this: "So too did a lot of the north's fighters do"? In other words, why the word "do" is missing?

Comment: The basic meaning of the sentence is "A lot of the north's fighters did that also".  You only need the main verb of the sentence (**do**) once; that's why it doesn't really make sense to say "So did the fighters do".  It would be like saying "The fighters did do that."  (Which would actually make sense if it were the *emphatic do*, but that's not what's being used here.)

Comment: Just gave up on adapting this [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/119593) question to this one. "So too" is idiomatic. _Too_ modifies _so,_ **not** the verb _did._

Answer (score 2):

**So too** in this sentence simply means **Also.** This is an idiom in English. The intensifier *too* modifies the adverb *so* (N.B: not the verb *do.*) In the [words of a questioner](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/119593) at our sister site ELU, "the main point of too is simply to emphasize the also-ness" of *so.*

With this understood, and after changing the word order, the sentence would read as follows:

> **Also** some of the social means and cultural criteria of the north did expand southward.

The author chose *so too* and placed the verb *do* at the beginning of his sentence as a matter of style.

Another sentence must have preceded this one, and it is that sentence to which *so* (and thus also the intensifier *too*) refers here. In other words, the context must be something like:

> The trade in silver pressed more and more prospectors to the south. *So too* did some of the social means and cultural criteria of the north expand southward.

Comment: *Also (something) did (verb)* seems to me at least unnatural or relatively unlikely. It illustrates the meaning well, but I think it's not simply a stylistic alternative.

Comment: @JimReynolds  I think you'll find constructions like this one rather common in formal writing.